# singleton class object in typescript

Tags: node.js, design-patterns

I have created a rest api using node js, and create a singleton class to access a database connection. if two user want to access my api in that case i want to know whether there is two object is create or one at the server.

Comment: Nobody can really answer for sure without seeing the relevant code.  Questions here about code SHOULD include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs, the only automatic per-request variables are `req` and `res` (that the http server creates for you for each incoming request).  Your other server variables (whether global or module level variables) are shared across all requests.

So, if you created a singleton with module scope, that would be shared among all request handlers from all users.

For a more specific answer, please add the relevant code to your question and we could answer more specifically about your actual code.

Comment: @VivekChaudhary - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, please tell us what else you need to know.